# Equivalence in $\infty$-categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, reference-request

In every $n$-category (weak or strict) can be defined the concept of equivalence via a recursive definition:
* an equivalence in a set ($0$-category) is just an identity;
* for each $n \in \mathbb N$ an equivalence between two object (or $0$-cell), let say $a$ and $b$, in a $n+1$-category is just a $1$-cell $f \colon a \to b$ such that exist a $1$-cell $g \colon b \to a$ and two $2$-cells $\alpha \colon g \circ f \to 1_a$ and $\beta \colon f \circ g \to 1_b$ which are equivalence into the $n$-categories $\hom(g\circ f, 1_a)$ and $\hom(f \circ g, 1_b)$ respectively.
There is a good formal definition of equivalence also for $\infty$-category?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some precise definitions and results, see this [paper](http://www.cheng.staff.shef.ac.uk/duals/duals1103.pdf) by Eugenia Cheng.

Comment: To be honest, I think that paper is seriously misleading.  Her "Unsound definition" 5 is actually a perfectly sound definition; you just have to interpret it coinductively.  Unfortunately, coinductive definitions don't seem to be as widely known as inductive ones.


Comment: That's interesting. But offhand, "seriously misleading" sounds like a pretty strong way to put it, as if the paper is invalid somehow. (I believe the paper predates Eugenia's involvement with corecursive definitions of $\infty$-categories. Aside from the label "unsound definition", is there anything actually wrong with the paper?) 

Comment: I'm sorry if I came on too strong.  I didn't mean to say there was anything wrong with the paper; it's a very nice paper overall!  I just meant that specifically *in the context of the question* "how to define equivalences in &infin;-categories?", I think it is a misleading reference to give.  To my mind, the best definition is actually the coinductive one, which that paper asserts to be unsound.


Comment: Ouch. :-) Could you provide a better reference, then? 

Comment: I hope that Eugenia, if she is reading this, won't take offense at my comment.  The fact that coinductive definitions are meaningful seems generally to be a secret well-kept by computer scientists and rarely taught to mathematicians.  I only fairly recently learned it myself.  In fact I learned it by reading a coinductive definition of infinity-equivalence, thinking "that's nonsense", and going to look it up and finding out that it wasn't!

Comment: And yes, I should actually give a reference, shouldn't I, instead of just criticizing?  (-:  See my answer below.

Comment: I imagine Eugenia doesn't read MO, so probably no worries there. *And since her definition is equivalent to the one you prefer*, and maybe more readily understandable for people not accustomed to coinductive definitions (which take some getting used to), it's not really such a terrible reference to give, is it? Just shield your eyes to "unsound definition" (which isn't actually essential to the paper except in a didactic sense). Better yet, take it for what it is: a manifestation of something that the author wasn't aware of at the time. 

Comment: I didn't mean to say I think anything is wrong with her *definition*.  But just generally, in any situation where there are two equivalent definitions of something, even if one of the definitions is easier to understand, I wouldn't want to recommend to a newcomer a reference which claims that the other definition is "unsound", at least not without simultaneously telling them that the other definition is actually just as good.  I feel this way even if I know they aren't going to spend the time to actually understand the other definition themselves.


Comment: Point taken, and I basically agree. I didn't know about this other reference, and I'm glad I do now, and I appreciate your telling us about it (mine was the first upvote). I bristled because a few comments ago, it sounded like you were suggesting *I* was being misleading. Truth is, at the time of reading the question, I knew Eugenia had written something about the topic, I managed to track it down, and I merely passed it on. I certainly hadn't picked up on the flaw that you astutely pointed out. But your observation was expressed rather strongly; your last comment seems more balanced in tone. 

Comment: (You know, someday I'd like to meet you in person, Mike. Internet communications just aren't the same thing, are they? :-) 

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry that my first comments were too strong.  Unfortunately, I find that that sort of miscommunication is easier to slip into on the Internet, and moreover it then gets then recorded forever for everyone else in the world to read.  (-:

Answer (score 5):

A concise coinductive definition can be found, for the case of strict ∞-categories, in the paper "A folk model structure on omega-cat", [arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/0712.0617).  This can be unraveled in order to become equivalent to Eugenia's more explicit version.

Comment: This is very interesting!  Presumably you can unroll the coinduction to make a definition in terms of the existence of an infinite binary tree of higher morphisms (although I don't know if this is a useful thing to do).

Comment: Yes, as I said, this version can be unraveled into Eugenia's.  Perhaps (probably?) for some applications this would be useful.